# admob Interstitial auto closing

Tags: ios, admob, google-dfp

I am using DoubleClick (dfp) ads of admob.
I want to close/dismiss **Interstitial** after few seconds.
(Just if user didn't click on the ads).

I can do `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated` afterDelay, but it's closing the ads even user click on them.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

After many attempts it turns out:
Apparently it is not possible to do this with interstitial
The best way to make a splash screen is normal adview and make it resize to the size of the screen.

Comment: actually this is a wrong way to implement this feature. You can see above you, Daniel's answers with the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

you have to implement `<GADInterstitialDelegate>` delegate and implement the delegate's method `interstitialWillDismissScreen:(GADInterstitial *)ad`

```
#import "MainViewController.h"
#import "GADInterstitial.h"

@interface MainViewController ()<GADInterstitialDelegate>
@property(nonatomic, strong) GADInterstitial *interstitial;


@end

@implementation MainViewController


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];


   self.interstitial = [[GADInterstitial alloc] init];
   self.interstitial.adUnitID = @"ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/4411468910";

    GADRequest *request = [GADRequest request];
   // Requests test ads on simulators.
   request.testDevices = @[ GAD_SIMULATOR_ID ];
   [self.interstitial loadRequest:request];


}
-(void)interstitialDidReceiveAd:(GADInterstitial *)ad
{
    NSLog(@"interstitialDidReceiveAd successfully");
    [ad presentFromRootViewController:self];
}
-(void)interstitialWillDismissScreen:(GADInterstitial *)ad{
  NSLog(@"interstitial is going to dismiss");


}
```

this is have to close your interstitial automatically.